# Compute $\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{m+1}}{i\lambda}(1+e^{-i\lambda\frac{2}{2^{m+1}}}-2e^{-i\lambda\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to compute the 
$S=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{m+1}}{i\lambda}(1+e^{-i\lambda\frac{2}{2^{m+1}}}-2e^{-i\lambda\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}})=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{m+1}}{i\lambda}(1+(e^{-i\lambda\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}}-2)e^{-i\lambda\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}})$

λ is just a real constant.

any strategies? This is homework so I prefer no solutions please.

By the ratio test (the ratio goes to 0), I showed it converges.

Mistake somewhere:

By the Taylor expansion: $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}2^{m+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}2^{m+1}\frac{(-i\lambda)^{k}}{k!}(\frac{1}{2^{km-m-1}}-\frac{1}{2^{km+k-2-m}})$

$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}2^{m+1}+2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}4\frac{(-i\lambda)^{k}}{k!}\frac{2^{k-1}-1}{2^{k-1}-1}$

$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}2^{m+1}+2e^{-i\lambda}=\infty$

Comment: What is $\lambda$? If it's a constant, are there any restrictions as to its value?

Comment: $\lambda$ is just a real constant.

Comment: Aren't the exponents of the second and third terms inside the parenthesis equal? if so, you could simplify the series...

Comment: There is some telescoping between successive terms.

Comment: By the way where did this series come from?

Comment: This series comes from this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929872/deriving-spectral-density-of-white-noise-from-brownian-motion